# scala: Type mismatch when trying to concatenate two lists or create a list

Tags: scala, generics, binary-tree

Type mismatch when trying to concatenate two lists or create a list.

I am trying to implement a very simple binary tree with Scala and do an inorder traversal,
and insert the values of tree node into a `List` during the traversal process and return that `List` when traversal is done.

My tree definition is as below:

```
abstract class Tree[+T]

case class Node[T](v: T, lft: Tree[T], rght: Tree[T]) extends Tree

case class Leaf[T](v: T) extends Tree
```

And my inorder traversal method is as below:

```
object prog {
    def inorder[T](t: Tree[T]): List[T] = t match {
        case Node(v, lft, rght) => inorder(lft) ++ (v::inorder(rght))
        case Leaf(lf) => List(lf)
    }
}
```

The code is rejected by Scala compiler with the following error message:

```
tree.scala:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[T]
        case Node(v, lft, rght) => inorder(lft) ++ (v::inorder(rght))
                                                ^
tree.scala:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : lf.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: T
        case Leaf(lf) => List(lf)
                            ^
two errors found
```

I goolged a lot but could not figure out what is wrong with my code. Any hint would be
appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case class Node[T](v: T, lft: Tree[T], rght: Tree[T]) extends Tree

case class Leaf[T](v: T) extends Tree
```

should be:

```
case class Node[T](v: T, lft: Tree[T], rght: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]

case class Leaf[T](v: T) extends Tree[T]
```

Comment: Actually I am surprised why the compiler does not complain with:  case class Leaf[T](v: T) extends Tree

Comment: I think the compiler "helpfully" infers `Tree[Any]` here.